# Keyboard locks in IntelliJ IDEA on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, intellij

Could you help me with hell of a weird issue? 
I use Intellij IDEA 13 on Ubuntu 14.04, and from time to time my keyboard completely (yep, completely, it's not about shortcuts) locks in IDEA. I still can do anything I want in IDEA with my mouse, also I can use the keyboard everywhere else except IDEA. And it can be fixed only by restarting IDEA so far.

Can anybody give a hint, please?

Comment: Can it be that your keyboard is simply being captured by some field inside IntelliJ? Is it a random thing or does something specific trigger it?

Comment: I don't think some field can capture keyboard like that, but I'll check it more precisely next time. And it seems to be random thing.

Comment: My collegue and I are experiencing precisely the same thing (same OS and IntelliJ 13.1.4). I have to restart IntelliJ once every few hours (I'm able to use Alt-F4, though) - extremely annoying. I also find it to happen completely randomly. Last time I was in the middle of editing an HTML file. Not while pressing a shortcut.

Comment: I had two instances of IntelliJ running and they both froze. Don't know if it's relevant, but when I close the IDE, detaching a running application server normally takes very short time. After a freeze happens, I have to cancel that because it doesn't seem to finish.

Comment: Open IDEA log file `idea.log` from menu `Help > Show Log in Files` and look, what exceptions are thrown out. I have a same problem, but, unfortunately, I couldn't find information on it.
If you don't find the solution, address in IDEA bugtracker.

Comment: @injecto OK, thanks for the advice. I'll do it next time the bug appears.

Comment: I have had this problem too suddenly keyboard shortcut does not work (Intellij Idea 13 in Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Check out this bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23472 Killing ibus-deamon process fixed it for me.

Comment: This is a Java issue that effects other Java Swing GUI's including SOAP UI. "ibus-daemon -rd" fixes the issue as well

Comment: I had similar problem with IntelliJ IDEA 2016 Build IU 145.597
with Ubuntu 14.04. Using this code in console: ibus-daemon -rd it worked for me !

Answer (score 248, accepted):

There is a [an open issue in jetbrains youtrack for intellij idea](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860) that recommend two solutions:

1. Keyboard input may be unlocked by restarting IBus daemon from a console:

   ```
   ibus-daemon -rd
   ```
2. IBus can be disabled for IDEA by unsetting env. variable XMODIFIERS, but ability to input national characters in IDEA will be lost:

   ```
   XMODIFIERS="" idea.sh
   ```

I have used the second one and fixed my problem.

Comment: > "ibus-daemon -rd" from a console. 

That worked! Great-great thanks!)

Comment: 6 months later, Option 1 is no longer recommended as it may cause JVM crash :/

Comment: What do you mean national characters,  @Mike, it worked for me today June the 2th

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI Yes, it works; it's just that it's not a long term solution as it might cause JVM crashes (some users have reported it in the open issue).

Comment: "ibus-daemon -rd" - I'm seriously considering to tattoo this on my arm.

Comment: @BalázsMáriaNémeth Better yet, is to open keyboard settings, and add the command to a custom keyboard combination; just tested it with my Alt+Shift+Ctrl+*, for instance. ;)

Comment: "ibus-daemon -rd" is love

Comment: Last update on the issue (Jun 17 2015) recommends to `export IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1`

Comment: Interesting facepalm moment: Adding 'XMODIFIERS="" idea.sh' to your bashrc opens IDEA each time a new shell window opens -- so 5 copies for me at startup. Need to add export:  'export XMODIFIERS="" idea.sh' .

Comment: I'm having the same issue with IDEA 2018.3 on Ubuntu 18.04, and can confirm that the suggested fix still works.

Comment: confirmed on 20.04. Another fix is to open Language Support and set Keyboard input method system to none.

Comment: I'm going with pkill -f ibus-daemon...  I have had lockups about 5x per day... for weeks... on Ubuntu 18.04 with the latest Intellij 2020 download... I really don't care about a silly Ibus feature... I care a LOT about Intellij working reliably.

Answer (score 14):

I was able to solve it with what I found [here](https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5485279?tstart=0) that is basically adding `export XMODIFIERS=""` on `idea.sh`

Comment: seems to work here!

Answer (score 10):

1. **Temporary solution**: simply execute `ibus-daemon -rd` on the terminal.
2. **Permanent solution**: the  [01 Oct 2015 update on the issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860) recommends to:

> Either upgrade IBus to version 1.5.11 or add `export
>   IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1` to your `~/.profile`, then restart a session.
>
> Alternatively, you can turn off IBus at `System Settings | Language
>   Support | Keyboard input method`.

*IDEA 15 will show a warning if an incompatible version of IBus is in use.*

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this out and its working so far but I'll update if it freezes up again. I've seen a suggestion on youtrack that suggests to turn off iBus which seems to interfere particularly because of it's use of the ctrl + space shortcut to change language settings. You can do that by going to:

language support > keyboard input method system > none

[image]

**** UPDATE *****

After running it for a while this technique still didn't work as I kept freezing. I guess for now I'll stick to the following workaround to restart ibus which is a bit inconvenient but what can you do.

go into terminal

type:

```
ibus-daemon -rd
```

Comment: thanks, `ibus-daemon -rd` is what I was looking for.