# Random Mouse Movements Using Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mouse, cursor

Recently, my mouse cursor has been randomly moving slightly left and right. It happens at random intervals with a different move patterns.  I am running Ubuntu 15.10 on a Lenovo ThinkServer.  I use a wired mouse.  I tried another wired mouse and I have the same problem.

I disconnected the network, checked for viruses(ClamAV) and open network ports (using `sudo netstat -tulpn`) to no avail.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Few times observed same bug on 
Linux 4.4.0-59-generic #80~14.04.1-Ubuntu x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Just got idea why it could happen and did not check yet. It might be because ibus-daemon issue that affects keyboard health which is [known issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501907/keyboard-locks-in-intellij-idea-on-ubuntu-14-04) for IntelliJ Idea in Ubuntu. So, should this behavior still appears time to time, try to kill ibus-daemon once you face it. It helps to resolve Idea's keyboard stuck issue.

Comment: After long hunting the source of the issue was found. Turning off touchpad of the laptop resolves mouse racing. As far as you had it not on a laptop, I assume it is pointing device drivers for Ubuntu issue. Although complete fixing is hard as reproducing is not stable and looking for proper driver can take valuable time.