# ubuntu locks using IDE

Tags: 14.04, ide

I have Ubuntu 14.04

When I use Geany or PyCharm IDEs the system will lock up completely (usually after some fast scrolling the text window e.g. using the mouse wheel)

The same effect is not observed using Kate. I can get a freeze within a minute using Geany or PyCharm, but I can use Kate for weeks with no problem

Can someone please give me a hint where to look to solve this (maybe Geany and PyCharm use java (just a guess) and this might be significant)

EDIT:

using PyCharm I also see this message

```
IBus prior to 1.5.11 may cause input problem. See IDEA-78860 for details.
```

I'm using 1.5.5. Might this be relevant?

[RE-EDIT 3 June 2016]
I have tried PyCharm on a 'clean' (new) Ubuntu 14.04 set up and it works perfectly. So clearly there is some conflict here. can someone suggest what it might be?

Comment: PyCharm, for 100% certain, uses Java, as that's the language it's written in.

Comment: Thanks Stevie - might that cause a problem?

Comment: @Psionman Yes, even with my system and Java tuned properly PyCharm still occasionally freezes up my system.  The IBus issue hasn't impacted anything in my system and it uses that older IBus too.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas. Looks like there's no resolution to this problem then :(

Comment: II was looking a round for ibus questions, here are two may be related  https://askubuntu.com/questions/501907/keyboard-locks-in-intellij-idea-on-ubuntu-14-04?lq=1 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/781956/mozc-on-eclipse-etc-not-working-16-04-lts . All intellij, eclipse & SzeneBuilder are built on java.