# Mozc on eclipse etc. not working 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, eclipse, ibus, mozc

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and want to write Japanese in all applications. I've installed mozc and it works in some applications but not in Eclipse or SzeneBuilder. I also tried to install qt4 ibus but it didn't help.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT1**:

Output of `env | grep -iE "im=|im_"`

```
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
QT4_IM_MODULE=fcitx
GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
```

Output of `ibus read-config`

```
SCHEMA: org.freedesktop.ibus.general
  dconf-preserve-name-prefixes: ['/desktop/ibus/engine/pinyin', '/desktop/ibus/engine/bopomofo', '/desktop/ibus/engine/hangul']
  use-system-keyboard-layout: true
  embed-preedit-text: true
  enable-by-default: false
  use-global-engine: true
  use-xmodmap: true
  switcher-delay-time: 400
  version: ''
  engines-order: @as []
  preload-engines: @as []
  xkb-latin-layouts: ['ara', 'bg', 'cz', 'dev', 'gr', 'gur', 'in', 'jp(kana)', 'mal', 'mkd', 'ru', 'ua']
SCHEMA: org.freedesktop.ibus.general.hotkey
  next-engine: ['Alt+Shift_L']
  disable-unconditional: @as []
  enable-unconditional: @as []
  trigger: ['Control+space', 'Zenkaku_Hankaku', 'Alt+Kanji', 'Alt+grave', 'Hangul', 'Alt+Release+Alt_R']
  previous-engine: @as []
  prev-engine: @as []
  next-engine-in-menu: ['Alt+Shift_L']
  triggers: ['<Super>space']
SCHEMA: org.freedesktop.ibus.panel
  x: -1
  property-icon-delay-time: 500
  y: -1
  lookup-table-orientation: 1
  show: 0
  xkb-icon-rgba: '#415099'
  auto-hide-timeout: 10000
  show-im-name: false
  follow-input-cursor-when-always-shown: false
  custom-font: 'Sans 10'
  show-icon-on-systray: true
  use-custom-font: false
```

Output of `dpkg -l ibus*`

```
    Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  ibus           1.5.11-1ubun amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - core
ii  ibus-anthy     1.5.6-1      amd64        anthy engine for IBus
un  ibus-clutter   <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-doc       <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-el        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-googlepin <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  ibus-gtk:amd64 1.5.11-1ubun amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - GTK+2 sup
ii  ibus-gtk3:amd6 1.5.11-1ubun amd64        Intelligent Input Bus - GTK+3 sup
ii  ibus-mozc      2.17.2116.10 amd64        Mozc engine for IBus - Client of 
ii  ibus-qt4       1.3.2-2build amd64        qt-immodule for ibus (QT4) (plugi
ii  ibus-table     1.9.1-3ubunt all          table engine for IBus
un  ibus-table-arr <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-can <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-can <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-can <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-can <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-can <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-can <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-cns <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-com <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-eas <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-eas <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-emo <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-erb <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-erb <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-ipa <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-jyu <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-lat <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-qui <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-qui <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-qui <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-qui <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-rus <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-scj <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-str <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-tha <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-tra <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-tra <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-viq <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-wu  <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-wub <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-yaw <none>       <none>       (no description available)
un  ibus-table-yon <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Comment: Could you [edit] question and add output of `env | grep -iE "im=|im_"` ,  `ibus read-config` , `dpkg -l ibus*` .  Eclipse or SzeneBuilder both are build on java, so it could same issue as Intellij IDE. Try solutions in  https://askubuntu.com/questions/501907/keyboard-locks-in-intellij-idea-on-ubuntu-14-04